# How do I make my own custom QNetworkReply?

Tags: windows-10, qt5, qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I've been trying to create my own custom QNetworkReply class which return custom bytes from reply. I do return that class from my QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest() overload that I also did overload. My problem is, none of my function overloads are called and consequently the QWebView's request fail, as the reply is "corrupted". I've tried to take some inspiration from Qt tests lib's [`FakeReply`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebkit.git/tree/Source/WebKit/qt/tests/qwebframe/tst_qwebframe.cpp#n200) but I fail to make mine work.

Here's my code:

```
class FakeReply : public QNetworkReply
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FakeReply(const QNetworkRequest& request, QByteArray &data, QObject* parent = 0);
    ~FakeReply();
    QByteArray readAll();
    QByteArray read(qint64 maxSize);
    qint64 peek(char *buffer, qint64 maxlen);
    QByteArray peek(qint64 maxLen);
    qint64 size() const;
    virtual qint64 bytesAvailable() const;
    bool isFinished() const;
    virtual void abort();
    virtual void close();
    bool isSequential() const;
protected:
    qint64 readData(char*, qint64) override;
private:
    QByteArray data;
};
```

And the .cpp file:

```
FakeReply::FakeReply(const QNetworkRequest &request, QByteArray &bytes, QObject *parent)
    : QNetworkReply(parent),
      data(bytes)
{
    setOperation(QNetworkAccessManager::GetOperation);
    setRequest(request);
    setUrl(request.url());
    open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    setFinished(true);
    emit finished();
}

FakeReply::~FakeReply()
{
    close();
}

QByteArray FakeReply::readAll()
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::readAll() got called!";
    size_t len = data.length();
    const char *bytes = static_cast<const char*>(data.data());
    char *buffer = static_cast<char*>(malloc(len));
    ASSERT(buffer != NULL, "run out of memory");
    memcpy(buffer, bytes, len);
    QByteArray output;
    output.setRawData(buffer, len);
    data = data.remove(0, len);
    return output;
}

QByteArray FakeReply::read(qint64 maxSize)
{
    qDebug() << "QByteArray FakeReply::read() got called!";
    static char* buffer = nullptr;
    if(bytesAvailable() == 0) {
        return QByteArray();
    }
    size_t len = computeMaxNumberOfBytes(maxSize);
    if(buffer != nullptr) {
        free(buffer);
    }
    buffer = static_cast<char*>(malloc(len));
    ASSERT(buffer != NULL, "run out of memory");
    memcpy(buffer, data.data(), len);
    data = data.remove(0, len);
    QByteArray output;
    output.setRawData(buffer, len);
    return output;
}

qint64 FakeReply::peek(char *buffer, qint64 maxlen)
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::peek() got called!";
    size_t len = computeMaxNumberOfBytes(maxlen);
    memcpy(buffer, data.data(), len);
    return static_cast<qint64>(len);
}

QByteArray FakeReply::peek(qint64 maxlen)
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::peek(qint64 maxlen) got called!";
    QByteArray output;
    output.setRawData(data.data(), computeMaxNumberOfBytes(maxlen));
    return output;
}

qint64 FakeReply::size() const
{
    return data.length();
}

qint64 FakeReply::bytesAvailable() const
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::bytesAvailable()";
    return data.length();
}

bool FakeReply::isFinished() const
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::isFinished() got called!";
    return true;
}

void FakeReply::abort()
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::abort() got called!";
}

void FakeReply::close()
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::close() got called!";
}

bool FakeReply::isSequential() const
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::isSequential() const got called!";
    return false;
}

qint64 FakeReply::readData(char *, qint64)
{
    qDebug() << "FakeReply::readData() got called!";
    return 0;
}
```

the class is used like this:

```
QNetworkReply *MyNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation op, const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *outgoingData)
{
     QString path = request.url().path();
    QNetworkReply *reply = QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, request, outgoingData);

     if(path == QStringLiteral("/testing")) {
         QByteArray response = waitThenReadAll(reply);
         return new FakeReply(request, response);
     }
     return reply;
   }
```

Comment: So your MyNetworkAccessManager::createRequest() method doesn't get called? Could you post the *.h file for you acess Manager?

Comment: My `MyNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` does get called, what doesn't is all the methods from my `FakeReply`  returned by `MyNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with same issue I got the answer with some code example from [`here`](https://forum.qt.io/topic/87413/how-do-i-make-my-own-custom-qnetworkreply/3): What I was missing in my code was I was using `emit finish()` rather

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SIGNAL(readyRead()));
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SIGNAL(finished()));
```

That did work.

Comment: OK, I do see the problem. You got it to work. That's good. Your problem was that you called `emit finished()` in the constructor. Signals don't work there, since the object doesn't really exist yet (ie: the call to `new FakeReply(...)` didn't return yet), so there's nothing connected to it. But that is a good work around.